# What exactly is or how does a weak signal come into play in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I'm diving into `VHDL` and I couldn't really grasp the idea(?) of weak signals.

I understand that '`0`' and '`1`' are (strong) signals. This is quite common knowledge from my point of view.
How do weak signals now enter the arena?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of strong and weak drive in VHDL?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/208876/meaning-of-strong-and-weak-drive-in-vhdl)

Comment: Thanks but I've seen that before. As far as I see it is not really mentioned how a weak signal comes up? It is only mentioned that weak signals are used to model pull-up/down resistors. Why? In which way are they different from other signals?

Comment: Why? Because in the hardware, there maybe a pull up on that signal, so you have to model it somehow in VHDL code as well for simulation.

Comment: what does a pull up on a signal mean?

Comment: Google "pull up and pull down in circuits"

Answer (score 3):

VHDL had by default a 2-valued logic known as types `bit` and `bit_vector`. With IEEE Std. 1164, which was incorporated into VHDL itself, it got a 9-valued logic. In comparison, Verilog has only a fixed 4-valued logic (`X`, `0`, `1`, `Z`).

VHDL's `std_ulogic` type has:

- `U` - uninitialized
- `X` - strong unknown (error)
- `0` - strong low
- `1` - strong high
- `Z` - tri state
- `W` - weak unknown (error)
- `L` - weak low
- `H` - weak high
- `-` - Don't care

All objects are initialized with `type'left` if no default value is given. There are multiple subtypes like `x01z` with are compatible to the Verilog logic system.

Weak signals are intended to model pullups and pulldowns. Thus it's possible to simulate OneWire, I²C and similar busses with pullups and pulldowns.

Using strong and weak signals makes mostly sense when signals are driven by multiple sources. In such a cases, the type use should be based on `std_logic`, which adds a resolution function to the base type. A resolution function computes the effective values from multiple sources.

Example: `H` and `0` results in `0` (pullups and ground is ground).

Comment: Thanks a lot! What exactly is the meaning of modelling pullups and pulldowns? In digital logic, there are basically only two signals (high and low). So how does 1 differ from H?

Comment: `'1'` is Vcc and `'H'` is almost Vcc. Same for `'0'`, which is ground and `'L'` is almost ground. The voltage at a pullup or pulldown isn't exactly Vcc nor Gnd. VHDL allows you to model 4 values from Gnd via Low and High to Vcc. With this and a feature called *resolution function*, you can simulate in VHDL not only digital in-chip, but also  board-level. If you have a VHDL file with this line `SDA <= 'H';`, it adds a pullup driver (`'H'`) to the SDA line for an I²C communication link. When your chip drives `'Z'`, SDA will be `'H'`, but if you drive `'0'` it's `'0'`. Another chip will read low.

Comment: Thanks again! These are the exact words I feel like which are often missed out.

Comment: Hi, I would like to ask you another thing: Can you please help me to separate 'H' from 'Z'? I can say that 'H' is "almost 1 due to a pullup" (or pulldown?) and 'Z' corresponds to a Tri-State representing high impedance. For me this sounds quite identically.

Comment: Mybe it's better to continue this discussion on Gitter (Chat) for VHDL questions: https://gitter.im/vhdl/General